# Which resolution i have to use for .wmv video file?

Tags: java, android

I had a `.wmv` file and the size of `480 * 800`, I reproduce this file in `VideoView` using this method :

```
private void playVideo(){
videoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);

//      Here i set a path to video file
String videoSource = "android.resource://com.example.android.camera2basic/" + R.raw.movie;
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoSource));
videoView.setMediaController(null);

videoView.setOnCompletionListener(myVideoViewCompletionListener);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(myVideoViewPreparedListener);
}
```

Once the file has been changed (added duration) he stayed in the same format `.wmv` but the size was change in `808 * 1440` and now when I play video, nothing show, but the video is going... i can see time increase..

I have read and realized that the problem may be in high resolution ...

And then came the question:

1. In what resolution should be the file to be playing on all devices?
2. Or it is necessary to adjust the manually as necessary? By the code

Comment: WMV will not play on all devices in general. I recommend that you convert to a different format (e.g., MP4). You should also try playing your video from a regular file on the filesystem, instead of trying to load it out of a resource. There is no "magic resolution", but the higher the resolution of the video is, the less likely it is that loading it from a resource will work well.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks! It is really helped me when i converted file to MP4... But could you clear up please, how i can download file into file system? When user is downloading app and don't have opportunity connect to internet it will be a bug... Because he won't download video without internet... And the second question about resolution : which one you will suggest to use ?

Comment: You are welcome to ship the video as an asset or raw resource. However, I would copy it to the local filesystem before playback. Assets and resources are entries in the ZIP file that is an APK. That adds overhead to the playback process. You can get an `InputStream` on a raw resource via `openRawResource()` on a `Resources` object, then use standard Java I/O to copy the resource to a file. "And the second question about resolution : which one you will suggest to use ?" -- smaller is better, for bandwidth and storage. Beyond that, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: Sorry i am a rookie and don't understand exact, you mean for beginer file stored in app, but when user has downloaded app, file should move to file system on device? This way?

Comment: Correct. On powerful devices, with lower-resolution videos, you may be able to play the video straight from the resource. For less-powerful devices, with higher-resolution videos, I worry that playing directly from the resource will be too slow.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok i get idea)) And about resolution, but small files has a worse quality of picture... Or you mean that i should use middle. Exsample `800 * 400`?

Comment: "And about resolution, but small files has a worse quality of picture" -- yes. You have to decide for yourself, for your videos and for your users, what to use for a resolution. I cannot tell you that.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks!